# linux permission conflicts

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I'd like to ask you something that's bothering me for the last couple of days.
On my system I keep a folder called myscripts under my usual home folder.

What I tried to do is

```
chmod 500 myscripts
```

and pressed enter. After that I did

```
ls -l ~
```

to confirm and I got

```
dr-x------  2 Konos5 people    2048 Jun 21 22:51 myscripts
```

From what I understand I now should not be able to write anything within the myscripts folder. However if I type

```
touch ~/myscripts/hello.txt
```

the file hello.txt is normally created. How is that happening and what happened to the "no write" permission bit?

And one last thing. Before I change the permissions of that folder I had already kept the infamous youtube-dl script with -rwx- permissions. If I now run the script it will automatically download a youtube video and write it on my disk (within myscripts folder). Again, how is that possible since the folder's permissions are -rx- only?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you probably root? Please add the output of `whoami` or `echo $UID`.

Comment: I am `Konos5`. Not root. That's why I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you're using your school's server, I suspect your home directory is on [AFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System). AFS does not respect Unix permissions on directories at all, but there are AFS-specific permissions you can use instead. For example, see [here](http://web.njit.edu/info/afs.perms.html) for details.

Comment: I was just about to mention that. Indeed the server runs of AFS. If that's the case however then shouldn't we worry about security?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's not like AFS has no permissions system at all. It just happens to have its own system, and mostly ignores the Unix permission bits. See my link for details.

Answer (score 1):

If your home is not on a file system which doesn't respect unix file permissions (like ASF, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/439971/138199)), you are most probably **root**.

Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to write to the *myscripts* folder even if you were logged in as the owner *Konos5*. The only exception is the *root* user who "has always access to everything".

However, as owner you can always change back the access rights and give yourself write access again.

Comment: I am not root. I am using my school's server.

Comment: Is the folder a symlink?

Comment: @speakr `ls -l` would have shown that, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DarthAndroid Right, I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

You will always have access to the folder (of which you are owner) <= that was wrong, it should be "if you are root".

Comment: This is not correct, please see [here](http://superuser.com/a/439965/138199).